# Converting w/v to mole fraction

Tags: aqueous-solution, stoichiometry

If I have 10 mL 0.9% w/v $\ce{NaCl}$ solution, I can deduce that the solution contains 0.09 g of $\ce{NaCl}$.

Imagine that this is standard laboratory conditions and 1 ml = 1 g is acceptable.
Is the mass of $\ce{H2O}$ simply $\pu{10 g} - \pu{0.09g}$?

This would lead to mole fractions of $\pu{76.43}$% $\ce{H2O}$ and $\pu{23.56}$% $\ce{NaCl}$.

**Update**
I realised I had made some errors in my original question. Do the above percentages look right and should I express them as unitless fractions?

Comment: How many moles of NaCl are there in 10 mL of 0.9% w/v NaCl? Did you figure this out? Once you do this step, you will see that 99.5 mol percent NaCl it is not possible. BTW, These percentage units are discouraged in analytical chemistry because of their ambiguity.

Comment: In a very strict sense, this problem is indeterminate because we do not know about the contribution of NaCl to the solution volume. Let us ignore that. But the numbers are still wrong. How many moles do you get for (10-0.09) g water and 0.09 g NaCl?

Comment: Thanks for your patience. 9.91 g H2O => 0.5501 moles, 0.09 g of NaCl => 0.00154 moles. Therefore H2O => 99.72% and NaCl => 0.28%?

Comment: Yes, this is what I get as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that you have

> 10 mL 0.9% w/v NaCl solution

This is an unusual specification and as user M. Farooq pointed out it is ambiguous. So let's assume that this is a reagent that I am to add for some reaction. Is this:

$\quad$(1) 10 ml water (10 grams) and 0.09 grams of NaCl
$\quad$(2) 9.91 ml water (9.91 grams) and 0.09 grams NaCl
$\quad$(3) 10 ml aliquot of 99.1 ml water and 0.9 grams NaCl

Each of these would be slightly different. The gist is that (1) and (2) are different because the densities of the solutions will be slightly different as well as the volumes. (2) and (3) are different because the volumes will vary even though the densities are the same.

Pragmatically such reagent solutions are generally used in a large excess for whatever their use is, so the slight variations don't make any difference in the reaction. However it is just sloppy to give an ambiguous specification when a specific specification could and should be given.

**Significant Figures**

The other inconsistency with the question posed is with significant figures. The OP has specified 0.9% NaCl, but calculated "mole fractions of 76.43% H2O and 23.56% NaCl". You can't get four significant figures for the mole fraction when the NaCl concentration only has one significant figure.

Comment: In which sense the definition is ambiguous? It is uncommon but not ambiguous. It does require the knowledge of density or plugging the latter to be 1, as it would be with % m/m when operating with volumetric flask or cylinders. I read it as it is and not as in 1), 2), or 3). It seems to me that the answer to OP could have been a simple Yes (I did not check the values, by the way), accounting that s/he is aware of the assumption about density.

Comment: @Alchimista - So say you were to add this solution as a reagent for a reaction. Exactly what would you make? // As I said I doubt that pragmatically it would make any difference, but I gave three possible interpretations. Realistically I'd probably do some variant of my (3). Water and NaCl are cheap. It is a lot easier to weight out 0.9 grams than 90 milligrams. If I were going to dump 9/10th of a gold or platinum solution then that would be another matter. ;-)

Comment: I took it as an exercise. The only possible solution is to assume density to be 1. Of course pragmatically most likely I would have to use it for a work-up or something that probably I won't even worry about. The same happens all the time even if conc is expressed as m/m, that was my point. Point 3) is especially bizarre.

Comment: @Alchimista - I hadn't thought of (3) as bizarre, but I was an analytical chemist. I almost always did replicates when doing an analysis.

Comment: no doubt. Likely you had followed self-contained complete protocols. This is not.